# bash function fails with set -e

Tags: bash

I have discovered some strange behavior when using `set -e`.
A simple code: `[ ${var} } && echo "text"` works fine outside a function but causes the script to exit when the same code is in a function. This only occurs if `var=""`.

The code also works fine if I use `||` or if I set the var to something.
Has anybody got an explanation for this?

```
#!/bin/bash
#version 4.4.20(1)
#set -x
set -e
var=
[ ${var} ] && echo "Test before function"
echo "Before function"
function test {
    [ ${var} ] && echo "Test inside function"
}

test
echo end
```

Comment: The exit status of `test` itself is 1 when `[ ${var} ]` fails; that's what triggers the early exit, because you haven't guarded the call to `test`.

Comment: BTW, the correct test is `[ -n "$var" ]` or `[ -z "$var" ]`, depending on the result you want.

Comment: BTW, using `set -e` is a bad idea *in general* -- see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) for some specific exercises showing cases where its behavior is unexpected, surprising or unreliable; and the broader comparison at https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/ showing the many incompatibilities between different shells' implementations.

Comment: BTW, consider the POSIX-standardized syntax `funcname() {` instead of `function funcname {` in bash -- the latter is pre-POSIX ksh syntax offered for compatibility, but bash doesn't actually implement the special-case behavior that ksh uses when that syntax is in place (in ksh, it makes variables local by default; in bash, it does nothing but make your code incompatible with POSIX sh).

Comment: `[ ${var} ] && echo "Test before function" || true`

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following:

- `false && true` exits with exit status `false`.
- The default return value of a function is the return value of the last thing it ran.
- `set -e` is defined to cause early termination if any *unchecked* command ("unchecked" being a word which, in this context, has a complex, caveat-filled, version-dependent, nonportable, and otherwise often-surprising definition) returns an exit status other than true.

Thus, when you have a function that runs `a-false-thing && a-true-thing` as its last command before returning, the function itself will return false, and `set -e` will terminate execution if it considers the function's invocation "checked".

Comment: Thanks guys. Your help is much appreciated.